# How to call a JS function from Java Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

So I've been looking and I found some other questions in stackoverflow but they weren't explained and I didn't understand much. I'm trying to execute functions from a .js file. One of the functions is:

```
function getRSAKey(mod, exp, pass) {
    pubKey = RSA.getPublicKey(mod,exp);
    encrypted = RSA.encrypt(pass, pubKey);
    return encrypted;
}
```

As you see this function calls other functions, this is quite a big file and there's no way I can "translate" it to Java, so I have to call the .js file within it. So far I think I need to create an String with the .js file, so that's what I have in my .java file:

```
BufferedReader script = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rsa.js"));
Context context = Context.enter();
ScriptableObject scope = context.initStandardObjects();
```

How can I do to call the function getRSAKey with some given paramaters? Also I should handle the return in the .java file!

Thanks

Edit: I forgot to say that the script uses http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/ the class provided in the link. I was able to execute a script, but it says that 'ReferenceError: "BigInteger" is not defined.'

Comment: You mean other than how it is mentioned in the Rhino documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#callingJSfuns

Comment: yes, I want someone to explain it a little bit if they can, I'm not an expert and I don't want to copy-paste and change the variables